# ntfs mount problem + ntfsfix problem

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I install ubuntu and now my windows can't boot and ubuntu too!
ubuntu error message is same to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395295/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-while-booting)! and windows error is "A disk read error occurred"

I cant install windows but windows 7 installation disk can't detect my hdd and windows xp's disk show me a "blue screen" and active boot disk can't show my partitions.
I only can run ubuntu live disk and ubuntu detect and show me hdd partitions. but one of my drives can not mount in ubuntu.
When i try to open my drive, ubuntu show me this message:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x0) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x1).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

My hdd is not RAID.
I read same questions and find a solution! ntfsfix. But...
When i run ntfsfx:

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
Mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x0) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x1).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x0) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x1).
Remount failed: Input/output error
```

p.s. This partition is major for me.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from LiveCD, mount your root partition like this

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

then do `nano /mnt/etc/fstab` to add `noauto` option to this NTFS partition. It should be like `... ntfs defaults,noauto 0 0`. Ctrl+X to save, then reboot.

Comment: not works. `ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x0) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x1). failed to mount...`

Comment: I wonder, what mounts it now? Ok, try to prepend '#' to the same line now.