# How to fix "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist" on new installation?

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, root

I just installed 14.04.1 on a USB 2.0 drive. At startup, I'm prompted for the encryption key, which I enter. After that though, I get the following:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:  
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)  
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)  
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)  
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)  
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!  


BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)  
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs) _
```

I've never seen this before, and I have no idea what to do :'(

Comment: [Here](http://askubuntu.com/q/395295/62483) is another guy with the same problem but could not find the solution. It would be great if someone could provide a real solution

Comment: @Lucio 
thank you, and thanks for the edit.
I ended up giving up and reinstalling. It worked lol