# Unknown applications installed on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-uninstall

I have installed Ubuntu on a new laptop and I'm trying to learn how to use Linux. While searching the software store and installing several programming tools and then uninstalling them I have some leftover applications. One is called Login Window, another is Previews control and last but not least is Qt5 settings. All three are functional but I do not know how to uninstall them. I have tried using the terminal and commands for this received from ask.com. These three applications do not show up in the software app.

After reviewing the suggestions that were posted overnight I ran `apt-get autoremove --dry-run`.  The return was

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: If I was in your place, I would try a command: `sudo apt-get autoremove` — **but you should not do it immediately**! **First** read my answer on this page: https://askubuntu.com/a/1312081/1157519 and study the question and other answers too. You will learn that this is a very useful command, which however sometimes can have unexpected results (like breaking everything). But if you learn to use the `--dry-run` or, the shorter `-s` option with it, you can use it safely.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop uses the GNOME desktop, which is GTK3 based.  Qt5 settings apply to Qt5 apps (KDE/Kubuntu & LXQt/Lubuntu use Qt5) so the Qt5 will impact any Qt5 apps you have installed (not your GTK3 or GNOME apps).  You likely have some Qt5 apps installed that are changed by Qt5 settings unless you manually installed the Qt5 settings app yourself (unlikely I suspect) or you've not autoremove'd as per @Levente's suggestion which may cause it to be 'removed' (cleaned)

Answer (score 0):

after much research I have discovered what the programs are associated with and was able to delete them as root user. Thanks for the suggestions as they steered me in the right direction.