# Is "apt-get remove openssl -y" VERY DANGEROUS?

Tags: ssh, ssl

Just ran this and it looks unancellable.

MUCH is being cleared out.

I simply want to remove and re-insall all ssl ssh apparatus.

There is horrible version mismatch.

Comment: The dangerous part is the `-y`. You just told the system that you don't want a chance to review or cancel. Do not interrupt. When it finishes, install `ubuntu-desktop`, which should reinstall most of what was lost.

Comment: Yes, the '-y' was an accident copy/paste.

Can't believe Ubuntu upgrade has left in broken ssl ssh state. These are fundamental things. They should be packaged together I on Ubuntu surely.

Comment: _"I 90% understand the risk scope of the command."_ - It seems you got bitten by the other 10% though ;) - _"I generally expect ssh and family to just work and I NEVER want to touch them."_ - Then don't remove important packages! I don't know what problem you were having before this command, but the problems you have after this command are entirely of your own making.

Comment: @mathtick While I agree that an extra guard against removing "critical" packages might be useful, there's always two problems with such measures: 1) someone has to define which actions are "extra dangerous", and there's always a lot of different ways you can mess up a running system; 2) there always needs to be a way of doing it when you _really_ need to - in this case, you already turned off two levels of protection with `sudo` and `-y`, so if there was a third level of protection you might still have turned that off accidentally as well.

Comment: @IMSoP There is an extra level which guards against uninstalling packages labelled as “essential”, which you can't do with just `apt-get remove -y`. But that only covers things that are truly critical, basically the minimum to boot to a local shell. It doesn't cover things that not everybody would want, such as an SSH server.

Comment: `apt-get remove openssl -y` does not remove SSH. Not that “remove and reinstall” is a good idea in the first place: whatever problem you're trying to solve, this probably won't resolve it, or if it does then `apt-get install --reinstall` would be a less risky way of resolving it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### You can easily reinstall the removed packages.

Apt has a history file. This file is `/var/log/apt/history.log`. Run the following command to view it in the terminal:

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

You will see a **Start date**, **Commandline** used, **Requested-By** username, etc.

So run:

```
grep -hA5 "remove openssl" /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "Remove"
```

This should print out the packages that were removed. The word "Remove" should only appear once, at the beginning of the list.

#### If this list appears to be what was removed, then proceed.

First, cd into your user's home directory and then send the list to a file named "removedpackages".

```
cd
grep -hA5 "remove openssl" /var/log/apt/history.log | grep "Remove" > removedpackages
```

#### Now we need to clean up the list before sending it to `apt`.

This command should print everything on a new line:

```
sed -e "s/ [a-z0-9(]/\n&/g" removedpackages
```

This should grep for only the package names (lines that begin with a blank space followed by a lower case letter or number).

```
sed -e "s/ [a-z0-9(]/\n&/g" removedpackages | grep '^ [a-z0-9]'
```

Now the packages should be listed in the form of packagename:amd64 or packagename:all or packagename:i386 etc.

If so, then send the list to a new file named removedlist.

```
sed -e "s/ [a-z0-9(]/\n&/g" removedpackages | grep '^ [a-z0-9]' > removedlist
```

#### Finally to reinstall the packages, send the contents of the file to `apt`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install $(cat removedlist)
```

And remove your work files:

```
rm removedlist removedpackages
```

---

##### An explanation of the options used for:

```
sed -e "s/ [a-z0-9(]/\n&/g"
```

- `-e` prints or echos the output instead of editing the file
- `s///g` is the standard form of a substitute string
- `[a-z0-9(]` match any blank space followed by a lowercase letter or number or open parenthesis.
- `\n&` substitute with a new line `\n` before the match `&`.

##### Also:

For `grep -hA5`

- `-h` says do not list the file name in the output and
- `A5` says to also list the 5 lines after the match

Comment: And luckily, since you only removed the packages (as opposed to using purge), you should've retained your configuration files and everything should be back to normal. Although, I suggest opening a specific question about the mismatch problem and please remember to include the exact error, copied and pasted.

Comment: Love this. Going to try to commit this "apt has history" to memory for exactly these scenarios.

Comment: Lucky that apt uses gnutls, not openssl :)

Comment: Even if apt did use openssl, the "openssl" package only contains the application binaries, not the libraries. The libraries are in libssl<version>.

Answer (score 11):

It's the operating system's command line interface.

In this environment, a lot of commands can become very dangerous, especially when they are being copy-pasted, and especially when unintended, or unaware options, such as `-y` are being left in them.

I seem to observe that a lot of people —novices, but on occasion, sysadmins alike— appear to learn to respect this environment only at their own, sometimes significant expenses.

In the meanwhile, [I suggest relying](https://askubuntu.com/a/1312081/1157519) on the `apt-get` command's `--simulate` or equivalent `--dry-run` options to review the impact of such commands without having to live with the consequences.