# Update grub in a chroot environment with root on a luks encrypted volume

Tags: grub2, luks, chroot

I want to move a system (all systems I am using are Ubuntu 16.04 based) from an unencrypted partition to a luks encrypted one (on the same disk).

To this end, I created a LUKS encrypted logical volume that contains a root and a swap partition. Then I copied the content of the existing partition to the new root partition using `dd`.
I have checked that this new root contains the proper directory structure and performed a disk scan of the partition.

The plan was to chroot to the new system and to update grub from there.

In detail, I am trying the following (which is a combination from  Ubuntu help pages and [How to reinstall grub from a liveUSB if the / partition is encrypted and there is a separate /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719409/how-to-reinstall-grub-from-a-liveusb-if-the-partition-is-encrypted-and-there-i) ):

```
# Unlock crypto file system
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 lukslvm 

sudo vgscan 
sudo vgchange -ay
sudo svscan

# Mount root file system
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /mnt
# Mount boot filesystem
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
# Mount required internal file systems
sudo mount -o rbind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/sys
## Additional LVM directories (for older systems)
sudo mount -o rbind /run/lvm /mnt/run/lvm
sudo mount -o rbind /run/lock/lvm /mnt/run/lock/lvm
# Enable DNS resolution
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
# Change to the encrypted system
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash

# Install required software
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup lvm2

# Edit /etc/crypttab
sudo printf "lukslvm\tUUID=%s\tnone\tluks\n" "$(cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda2)" | tee -a /etc/crypttab

# /etc/modules editieren
sudo echo "dm-crypt" >> /etc/modules

# Update kernel initramfs
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

echo "Edit /etc/default/grub as GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=\"kopt=root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root\""
sudo vi /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub

# Leave chroot environment
exit
# Write buffers to disk
sudo sync
# Unmount file systems
sudo umount /mnt/run/lvm
sudo umount /mnt/run/lock/lvm
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/boot
#
sudo swapoff -a
```

Unfortunately, it does not work out that way as `update-grub` does not seem to find the system installed on the encrypted partition.
It only find the existing installation on a different partition `/dev/sda3`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you forgot to create a proper /etc/mtap file

```
sudo cp /proc/mounts /mnt/etc/mtab
```

See https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Restore_Grub2

Comment: Thanks. This alone does not seem to fix it, even though the root in /dev/mapper is definitely in the mtab file.

Comment: If you are booting into this device, do you see the grub startup screen? If not, try the grub-install /dev/sda

Comment: Yes. The grub installation works fine for the unencrypted partition. The installation on the encrypted partition is just not listed.

Comment: Could perhaps the problem be that the ubuntu installation on the encrypted partition resides on the same harddisk as the one that I am booting from? There is a Q&A that suggests this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335247/two-linux-distributions-grub-does-not-detect-other-one

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact, that you are re-using the kernels in /dev/sda1 (aka /boot) for both root-filesystems (devmapper and /dev/sdaX). The grub script in /etc/grub.d/10_linux iterates in the function linux_entry() over the kernels found in /boot. I don’t how it behaves in your case…
Try adding a “set -x” at the beginning of the linux_entry() function and check what is happening to your kernels. The “set -x” will generate huge amount of output. But without more details of the process, I don’t see how you can solve this issue.

Comment: To exclude the idea that the cause are the two systems on `/dev/sda`, I wiped the unencrypted one now and it still fails.

Comment: Can you paste the output of these commands in your chroot env:

$ /usr/sbin/grub-probe --target=device /
$ /usr/sbin/grub-probe --target=device /boot

Comment: Ok, thanks, will do that latter. Meanwhile I managed to boot into the system using SuperGrub2Disk`. Installing grub still fails.

Comment: The output of both of the commands is `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`.

Comment: I have tried boot `boot-repair` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) which also didn't help me.

Comment: I think you found the reason, why grub is not generating the new entries. $ /usr/sbin/grub-probe --target=device /boot should give you /dev/sda1. Since this is the location of the un-encrypted boot device. I'dont now why grup-probe is not working as expected. Calling grub-probe with --verbose might give you some more information.

Comment: I am afraid not. Now after I added `/boot` to `/etc/fstab`, your command finds `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: Okay, now I don't see any easy way out of this. You need to debug the /etc/grub.d/10_linux script, if you want it to work:
Add a "set -x"  after the "#! /bin/sh" and watch the output of "sudo grub-mkconfig 2>&1 | less -S"

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately that did not solve it for me either, but I managed to do it by cloning my system again, copying the configuration/partition structure from an installation that was full disk encrypted in the first place.