# How to access Advanced Options in GRUB?

Tags: grub-efi

I’m following this guide: https://askubuntu.com/a/910211

I searched for “Advanced Options” but there’s nothing displayed. Do i have to type something in the command line to access to them?

Help? :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure advanced options are listed upon Grub at boot... You may just have to look for it...

Comment: <grub> Is the only thing displayed... the rest is a black ocean.

Comment: This sounds unusual of Grub... Perhaps you may want to consider reinstalling it?

Comment: I don’t think i have enough skill to do that... But if it is the only way i’ll try!

Comment: I mean an even easier option is just to reinstall Ubuntu...

Comment: I mounted Ubuntu with persistence in order to use it only “live”, without installing it. Thanks for the help anyway! :)

Comment: @neilpare When you read my answer below, do not try to upgrade the kernel under a USB-Live session with persistence. I've read that it tends to break things.

Comment: I always use grub-customizer to access grub settings.

Answer (score 3):

1. Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where you can enter the GRUB menu.) With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GRUB menu. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GRUB screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

   The timing when to press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to [I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/87409/).
2. From the GRUB screen select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image]
3. A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

   [image]

Answer (score 2):

From:  [Grub2/Submenus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus):

> The submenu feature was introduced by Ubuntu in GRUB 1.99. The default
>   submenu title is "Previous Linux versions" and appears immediately
>   below the first kernel menuentry (and its associated recovery mode
>   option, if enabled) in the main GRUB menu.

So if you are a fresh install and don't have a previous Kernel version to boot to the sub-menu **Advanced Options** may not appear.

If this is true in your case, after a Kernel Update the sub-menu will appear.