# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at loading screen (Wayland disable fix not working)

Tags: boot

This installation ran fine for about a week, but today it refuses to boot. I've tried several fixes from other questions, in particular https://askubuntu.com/a/1099111/333715. I've also tried install `lightdm` instead of Wayland to no avail. `journalctl -b-1` shows no obvious errors.

The really curious thing is that it the first time this happened, I booted into the Windows partition on the same drive to see if that still worked, then booted back to Ubuntu, which succeeded. However, it has failed every time since then.

Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: What messages do you get when pressing ESC? Do you have autologin? Can you switch to a CLI (Crtl+Alt+F1)?

Answer (score 1):

For my system it was not related to wayland. After I installed my nvidia card driver problem got fixed.
Enter via recovery mode and install nvidia driver if you have nvidia driver card.