# Ubuntu 18.04 is not showing desktop - fresh installation

Tags: boot, 18.04

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and updated, after update when I restarted it's got stuck on Ubuntu loading screen, but I'm able to connect with ssh and TeamViewer without any problem.
Found this topic [Ubuntu 18.04 is stuck at loading screen after new installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033463/ubuntu-18-04-is-stuck-at-loading-screen-after-new-installation) and tried this solution :

```
pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and uncomment the `WaylandEnable=false` line, not solved.

Inxi output of the hardware:

```
    System:    Host: server1 Kernel: 5.3.0-53-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 0 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME H310M-D R2.0 v: Rev X.0x serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: 0407 date: 08/14/2018
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i3-8100 (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3600 MHz 1: 880 MHz 2: 2842 MHz 3: 2597 MHz 4: 2410 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
           Display Server: N/A driver: i915 tty size: 252x65 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
Audio:     Card Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k5.3.0-53-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 4c:ed:fb:cb:d8:de
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 3000.6GB (0.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST3000DM001 size: 3000.6GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 2.7T used: 8.5G (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 34.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 0
Info:      Processes: 198 Uptime: 18 min Memory: 697.8/15877.6MB Init: systemd Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installing lightdm solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y lightdm
# choose lightdm as default loader when asked & restart.
```