# Processor microcode firmware update

Tags: 18.04, debian, dmesg, microcode

In Ubuntu 17.04 and 18.04 and Debian look like Kali when I enter `dmesg | grep 'microcode'` in the terminal I get the following results: 
`[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x24, date = 2018-01-21
[    0.032114] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1529357435 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 24
[    1.624457] microcode: sig=0x306c3, pf=0x10, revision=0x24
[    1.624585] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.`
why?

I also get this error:

```
[ 0.032112] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1529357026 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 24
```

Why?

Comment: [    0.032112] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:306c3 TIME 1529357026 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 24

Comment: I managed to track down the error in your comment and it says that this error does not occur when booting to an earlier kernel version. Since I don't have your hardware, I can't test which kernel version would work. This link will help if you want to try booting to a different kernel version: [How to access Advanced Options in GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014634/how-to-access-advanced-options-in-grub)