# Why there are 2 versions of Linux after I upgrade the Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 14.06 to 18.04. At the boot screen, I press `ESC` and choose the `Advanced options for Ubuntu`. And I see 2 items:

- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-33-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 4.8.0-36-generic

Why there are 2 of Linux versions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Advanced Options in GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014634/how-to-access-advanced-options-in-grub)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older working kernels are automatically retained to help you recover in case of several types of possible kernel failure or incompatibility.

Ubuntu typically retains one older kernel, which rotates as new kernels are installed.