# Ubuntu 22.04 only boot normally via recovery mode

Tags: boot, networking, nvidia, display-resolution

After recent upgrade (`sudo apt upgrade -y`) my screen resolution is stuck at 640, neither ethernet nor wifi is being detected. I tried reinstalling nvidia drivers but the problem persists.

However, when I boot to recovery mode and select the option 'Resume normal boot', everything works fine (screen resolution, network etc.)

Configuration:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic 
Uptime: 16 mins 
Packages: 2355 (dpkg), 20 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 42.5 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i7-3770 (8) @ 3.900GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 
Memory: 2041MiB / 15958MiB
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The last update must have updated the kernel and changed the default kernel in the grub boot menu.

Step 1: Try booting with a different kernal from Advanced boot options (see how: [How to access Advanced Options in GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014634/how-to-access-advanced-options-in-grub)). I was successfully able to boot with `linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic` (this could be different for you system). If this doesn't work, choose recovery mode and choose the `root` (drop to the root shell prompt) option (see how: https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/). Ensure that you enable networking (just in case).

Step 2: Open terminal (or if you're already in the shell prompt) and use this command to check the kernels on your system:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

output:

```
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg              5.15.0-1021.26                          amd64        Signed kernel image intel-iotg
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1025-oracle                  5.15.0-1025.31                          amd64        Signed kernel image oracle
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic                   5.15.0-43.46                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic                   5.15.0-46.49                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-47-generic                   5.15.0-47.51                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic                   5.15.0-48.54                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic                   5.15.0-50.56                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic                   5.15.0-52.58                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic                   5.15.0-53.59                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic                   5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-56-lowlatency                5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                   5.15.0.56.54                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Step 3: Notice the kernel `linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic` in the list from step 1. I want grub to choose this as the default kernel.

Step 4: Use this command to find the kernel in grub.cfg

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Step 5: Find `menuentry` followed by `submenu`

Here, `menuentry` and `submenu` is exactly what you see in grub menu when you boot your computer. `menuentry` being at position - 0, `submenu` - 1
[image]

Notice that I have `menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-1025-oracle'` at position - 0 within the submenu. This is exactly what I don't want to boot to. We're going to change this.

Step 6: Find the kernel that worked, within the submenu. I found mine at pos - 2 (counting from 0)
[image]

Step 7: Exit nano, and type this command to edit the grub boot settings to set the default kernel

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Step 8: Set GRUB_DEFAULT =0 to GRUB_DEFAULT = "1>2"
[image]

Type Ctrl+o to write, Ctrl+x to exit

Step 9: update grub with new settings with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Step 10: reboot with `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same issue as this
[No network after latest update: Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04/1444061#1444061)

I solved the issue by uninstalling the kernels that were automatically installed:

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.15.0-1025-oracle linux-modules-5.15.0-1025-oracle linux-modules-5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg linux-modules-5.15.0-56-lowlatency
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem but with onboard bluetooth and audio since yesterday (05.12.2022). Additionaly my nvidia graphics (GT 730) couldn't load the correct driver anymore (obvious bad resulotion).

I first used [Shine J's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1443871/1655185) but used [GRUB customizer](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_Customizer/) as GUI. Reboot with the correct kernel. After that [removed the wrong new kernels like Angel suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/1444062/1655185). Problem solved, but had to enable bluetooth again. For bluetooth I enabled it in console:

```
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

After that I also have had to uninstall the nvidia graphic driver (which was the one for the wrong oracle kernel flavor):

```
sudo apt-get purge ^nvidia-
```

and install the driver with the correct flavor:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.15.0-56-generic
```

After a system reboot everything was back again. Thanks for your help! I was glad to see that I'm not alone with this problem.

This is my first post on askUbuntu so I couldn't upvote your questions nor the other helpful answers.