# network completely disconfigured after seemingly normal boot

Tags: boot, networking, 22.04, raid, ahci

So I woke up this morning to boot my ubuntu 22.04 on a dell latitude 3420 as usual but I got an error like this [Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu)

First answer suggested to go into BIOS change storage configuration from RAID to AHCI

So I did that, and it worked, I could boot normally, only to find the network completely missing

Got the suggestion to try and check the folders
/etc/network/interfaces
or
/etc/netplan
and found them not existant

I did nothing out of the ordinary the night before. Just booted today with this problem. What could've caused this? Now I have to reconfigure all my network stuff from scratch.

Edit: Actually, I'm sorry, perhaps there is something that may have contributed. Software updater keeps prompting to install security updates:
Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64bit x86 SMP
Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-1021 (objects)
Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg
Signed kernel image intel-iotg
other updates: ubuntu base

I kept hitting install now and it apparently installed everything ok, only for the same window with the same prompt to pop up 5 minutes later. I kept hitting install now over and over then I got fed up and hit remind me later. Only for it to also keep popping up every 5 minutes.

nmcli returns:
`docker0: unmanaged "docker0" bridge, some numbers here separated by double dots, sw, mtu 1500 lo: unmanaged "lo" loopback (unknown), zeroes separated by double dots, sw, mtu 65536`

lspci | grep -i ether returns:
`Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)`

Comment: Very simple thing to try: Boot a previous kernel version? Does the problem persists?

Comment: Yes that's something else I was about to try. Harder to do without network, so let me try and find a way

Comment: oh, I can see my wifi with `nmcli connection`, the only empty entry is device

Comment: So I have used this https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time to help me set up the grub menu because apparently it allows me to select multiple installed kernel versions. I did and I see 3 versions, 5.15.0-1025-oracle, which is at the top, and the option I'm assuming boots automatically, 5.15.0-56-lowlatency and 5.15.0-56-generic, so I chose this last one and it worked! Thank you @ChanganAuto for the suggestion and also Frobozz for the help. Now perhaps I should set this generic one as main, so gonna look into that now.

Comment: excellent.  feel free to delete all my red herrings :)

Comment: I asked a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04. So the advice is to boot to a 5.15.0-56 kernel and take future updates from there?

What's the difference between 5.15.0-56- lowlatency and 5.15.0-56-generic and is one recommended over the other?

What will happen to 5.15.0-1025-oracle and 5.15.0-1021-intel-iotg; will they get deleted from grub without further action?

Thanks.