# Generic 22.04 kernel won't auto update

Tags: kernel, updates

After losing all networking after a kernel update (see here for more details: [No network after latest update: Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04)) I am running on 5.15.0-1-56-generic. But I'm not being offered any kernel updates now. How can I get back on an update path that will also clear the faulty kernels from grub?

dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep ii:

ii  linux-image-5.15.0-1025-oracle                  5.15.0-1025.31                          amd64        Signed kernel image oracle

ii  linux-image-5.15.0-56-generic                   5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic

ii  linux-image-5.15.0-56-lowlatency                5.15.0-56.62                            amd64        Signed kernel image lowlatency

ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04                   5.15.0.56.54                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep ii`

Comment: dpkg output included, thanks.

Comment: Under Lubuntu, I have last kernel 5.15.0-56 generic. It is not updating automatically.

Comment: I've learned how to delete kernels via Synaptic, so am down to just 56-generic and have cleaned up grub. Haven't been offered a kernel update yet, but assume that will come. Any other advice is still welcome, thanks.

Comment: I hope that you have now, like me, been offered 57 generic and are on the right path again. I did this by deleting the unwanted kernels and updating grub so that 56 generic was default kernel to boot to (see the above link). I think 57 took awhile to come along because of the holidays.