# Can't connect to wifi in normal boot

Tags: boot, networking, brightness

I've been using this laptop for over a year now, with **Ubuntu 20.04** installed. The wifi card  is **Wi-Fi 6 AX200**. Since last week's ubuntu update (I regularly run `sudo apt update`), the WiFi wouldn't connect,keeps asking for password even if I put the correct password. However, if I boot in recovery mode, repair the packages and reboot, the wifi issue is solved, but only for that boot. In the next boot the issue comes back and I have to keep repeating the recovery mode step, however in this mode as expected multiple things are disabled (especially X and so I can't alter the screen brightness which is killing my eyes T_T). Please help figure out the issue with wifi.

There was also some message from snap before the incident, which I can't recollect, but I suspect that could be the issue. I can connect via LAN in normal boot though.

Attaching output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 48:9e:bd:48:69:37
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-56-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=163.122.193.64 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fb704000-fb704fff memory:fb700000-fb703fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 1a
       serial: f4:b3:01:3a:e9:cc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-56-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 cc-a0-66.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:37 memory:fb600000-fb603fff
```

EDIT:

I see multiple similar complaints in last few days. Links:

[No network after latest update: Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04?rq=1)

[Ubuntu 22.04 - just lost internet access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446431/ubuntu-22-04-just-lost-internet-access?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Generic 22.04 kernel won't auto update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446130/generic-22-04-kernel-wont-auto-update?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[No network after latest update: Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04)

[network completely disconfigured after seemingly normal boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1444190/network-completely-disconfigured-after-seemingly-normal-boot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Ubuntu 22.04 only boot normally via recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443718/ubuntu-22-04-only-boot-normally-via-recovery-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Plus a follow up question on getting the correct kernel:

[How to copy the kernel available in live usb to the system ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1447309/how-to-copy-the-kernel-available-in-live-usb-to-the-system-ubuntu-installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved with kernel update to `5.15.0-57-generic`