# Ubuntu 22.04 - just lost internet access?

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet

I have looked at a similar issue at: [No network after latest update: Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443835/no-network-after-latest-update-ubuntu-22-04/1446398?noredirect=1#comment2524638_1446398)
but I have a slightly different problem I think? I logged onto my Ubuntu 22.04 system today to  find that I could not acces the internet? In settings, it shows my wired connection operating at 1000Mb/s? I deleted the profile, rebooted and  then re-added the connection but no change? Software updater  also says "Check your internet connection"? I have disabled the firewall too, but no change.   I am a Linux novice but would appreciate any help please.  I am using my Windows 10 machine at present.

Resulst of the terminal commands: ping -c3 8.8.8.8 and: ls -al /etc/resolv.conf are:

media@media-Z68AP-D3:~$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=15.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=15.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=15.3 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.301/15.444/15.687/0.172 ms
media@media-Z68AP-D3:~$

media@media-Z68AP-D3:~$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 140 Nov 22 09:35 /etc/resolv.conf
media@media-Z68AP-D3:~$

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please follow the steps at the duplicate. You should be all set.

Comment: So I seem to have found  a solution myself.. I opened a VPN conection, which worked and allowed me to update everything. After rebooting I now have access to the web again. Not sure why- but something must have become corrupted somewhere, somehow. Anyway, problem solved !