# Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS hanging on regular boot, but works on recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, 20.04, nvidia

Recently, my system started hanging on boot. It displays the following message:

```
[0.544426] pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
/dev/nvme1n1p3: clean, 1485144/62472192 files, 167779507/249006720 blocks
[2.531523] dell_wmi_sysman: Unable to run on non-Dell system
[2.548158] dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
```

I have tried changing the kernel (following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443718/ubuntu-22-04-only-boot-normally-via-recovery-mode?newreg=e5bfb3946c5244fe8864f1f76bc09fd7) answer) and also tried changing (i.e. purging + installing) my NVIDIA driver to the following:

```
nvidia-driver-525-server (this one worked prior to this problem)
nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-535-server-open
nvidia-driver-535
```

The system hangs with all of them, but boots correctly with the default `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` driver. Additionally, if, instead of booting normally, I choose to boot on recovery mode and then select "resume" from the menu, the system boots correctly (but does not seem to load the nvidia driver correctly, `nvidia-smi` does not work). Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
Hardware Model:  Alienware Alienware M15 R7
Memory:  64.0 GİB
Processor:  12th Gen Intel® Core™ 17-12700H 20
Disk Capacity:  2.0TB
Graphics:  llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)
OS Name:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
OS Type:  64-bit

GNOME Version:  42.5
Windowing System:  X11
```