# Ubuntu 23.04 update disabled graphics drivers and the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, graphics

Some of these Ubuntu updates likes one I applied yesterday completely ruined my computer. I'm not on beta or anything but just some updates which I suspect included newer graphics drivers and something else disabled my keyboard and reduced my 4k screen to 1024x768... So I had to erase the disk and reinstall everything... several hours wasted and still now I notice my keyboard behaving much worse than before. Some updates are just dangerous. I wonder if next time this happens, there is a quicker way to fix this or am I the only one experiencing such issues?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try booting into ubuntu with one of the older kernels from grub. I started facing a lot of problems after some updates and then found out that everything was working fine on the older kernels.

Comment: No, I had no idea I could do that so I just erased the whole drive and installed everything again. Next time I should be ready to try that. Is there a simple guide to booting with older kernels?  Thank you!

Comment: So I'm not an expert or anything. But if you have grub in your system then whenever you boot into grub you will have an option saying Advanced Options for Ubuntu. On selecting that you will get a list of kernels into which you can boot. Check out this guide maybe it will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014634/how-to-access-advanced-options-in-grub