# Ubuntu studio (initramfs) shell, ALERT! /dev/mapper/ubuntu--studio--vg-root does not exist

Tags: initramfs

boys. When I turn on the PC I get this error, what should I do?

[dropbox image error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nymhcpuj5l15bk/P_20181218_202443.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Have you done any updates or changes to your system recently?  The error indicates something nasty is going on with your computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gave up waiting for root device, ubuntu--vg-root doesnt exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567730/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-ubuntu-vg-root-doesnt-exist)