# Ubuntu 20.04 kernel upgrade -> encrypted Volume group cannot be found + crypttab empty

Tags: updates, lvm, cryptsetup

I updated today, then rebooted. The outcome is that the volume group cannot be found and it drops out to BusyBox.

I tried:

- "vgchange -ay" out from the busybox -> did nothing.
- Booting with an older kernel -> same outcome.
- Then I started from a live CD.

I found this webpage: [Recovering from an unbootable Ubuntu encrypted LVM root partition](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/recovering-from-unbootable-ubuntu-encrypted-lvm-root-partition/), but my `/etc/crypttab` is empty.

Here you see how the filesystem is structured:

[image: lsblk --fs]

The two SSDs sda and sdb create on a 3ware controller the raid 1 array sdc. A softraid 1 is then initiated on the 2x 8TB HDDs (which are recognized by the BIOS, but cannot be accessed (unless I knew how) from the live CD even the crypt on the SSDs is opened up.

So I guess ... first things first... that I need to fix the volume group to be found during boot.

---

If I first unlock the crypt &  run `sudo vgchange -ay` on the live CD, then it looks promising:

```
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "hal9999-vg" now active
```

However after rebooting still the Volume Group cannot be found.

I read that this problem occurs in relation to LVM and initramfs, but I don't want to mess around randomly with my filesystems in order to avoid getting in bigger trouble.

In the meantime I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1105848/1102068). It flooded my crypttab, but `update-initramfs -u -k all` failed:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262' not
    found in /etc/crypttab
W: /sbin/fsck.crypto_LUKS doesn't exist, can't install to initramfs
```

After all this is the current status:

Output of `lsblk -fs`:

```
NAME                 FSTYPE            LABEL       UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
loop0                squashfs                                                             /rofs
sda                  linux_raid_member hal9999:0   853e3329-6076-8398-e0d8-19149c7d0d64
sdb                  linux_raid_member hal9999:0   853e3329-6076-8398-e0d8-19149c7d0d64
sdc1                 vfat                          94B1-AF12
└─sdc
sdc2                 ext4                          bbb39977-bf4a-4d8b-b524-7c29a85471d0   /mnt/boot
└─sdc
sdd1                 vfat              XUBUNTU 18_ 849C-7AF8                              /cdrom
└─sdd
hal9999--vg-root     ext4                          17c06541-b952-41a2-b28d-b37e49771625   /mnt
└─luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
                     LVM2_member                   JK4UPj-KdoV-yFe5-XBZW-cHFP-JCbV-JsLjPq
  └─sdc3             crypto_LUKS                   524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
    └─sdc
hal9999--vg-swap_1   swap                          cd5a6a21-dea3-46a9-a524-e43de19c0587
└─luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
                     LVM2_member                   JK4UPj-KdoV-yFe5-XBZW-cHFP-JCbV-JsLjPq
  └─sdc3             crypto_LUKS                   524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
    └─sdc
```

`/etc/crypttab`:

```
sdc3_crypt UUID=524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 none luks,discard

data /dev/md0 /root/drive_key luks
```

`/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`:

```
#
# Configuration file for the cryptroot initramfs hook.
#

#
# KEYFILE_PATTERN: ...
#
# The value of this variable is interpreted as a shell pattern.
# Matching key files from the crypttab(5) are included in the initramfs
# image.  The associated devices can then be unlocked without manual
# intervention.  (For instance if /etc/crypttab lists two key files
# /etc/keys/{root,swap}.key, you can set KEYFILE_PATTERN="/etc/keys/*.key"
# to add them to the initrd.)
#
# If KEYFILE_PATTERN if null or unset (default) then no key file is
# copied to the initramfs image.
#
# Note that the glob(7) is not expanded for crypttab(5) entries with a
# 'keyscript=' option.  In that case, the field is not treated as a file
# name but given as argument to the keyscript.
#
# WARNING: If the initramfs image is to include private key material,
# you'll want to create it with a restrictive umask in order to keep
# non-privileged users at bay.  For instance, set UMASK=0077 in
# /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
#

#KEYFILE_PATTERN=
CRYPTSETUP=Y
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#/dev/mapper/hal9999--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=bbb39977-bf4a-4d8b-b524-7c29a85471d0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=94B1-AF12  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/hal9999--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
/dev/mapper/data /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

It looks like the diagnosis "Ubuntu accidentally removed lvm and cryptsetup at the last update" may be the case.

I ran these commands:

```
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# mount /dev/mapper/sdc2 /mnt/boot
mount: /mnt/boot: special device /dev/mapper/sdc2 does not exist.
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/boot
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
root@xubuntu:/home/xubuntu# chroot /mnt
```

...and changed `/etc/fstab` to:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#UUID=524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/hal9999--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=bbb39977-bf4a-4d8b-b524-7c29a85471d0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=94B1-AF12  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/hal9999--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
/dev/mapper/data /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Now I'm getting this error on `update-initramfs -c -k all`:

```
   cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262' not
    found in /etc/crypttab
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262' not
    found in /etc/crypttab
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262' not
    found in /etc/crypttab
```

New output:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ lsblk --fs
NAME                 FSTYPE            LABEL       UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
loop0                squashfs                                                             /rofs
sda                  linux_raid_member hal9999:0   853e3329-6076-8398-e0d8-19149c7d0d64
sdb                  linux_raid_member hal9999:0   853e3329-6076-8398-e0d8-19149c7d0d64
sdc
├─sdc1               vfat                          94B1-AF12
├─sdc2               ext4                          bbb39977-bf4a-4d8b-b524-7c29a85471d0   /mnt/boot
└─sdc3               crypto_LUKS                   524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
  └─sdc3_crypt       LVM2_member                   JK4UPj-KdoV-yFe5-XBZW-cHFP-JCbV-JsLjPq
    ├─hal9999--vg-root
    │                ext4                          17c06541-b952-41a2-b28d-b37e49771625   /mnt
    └─hal9999--vg-swap_1
                     swap                          cd5a6a21-dea3-46a9-a524-e43de19c0587
sdd
└─sdd1               vfat              XUBUNTU 18_ 849C-7AF8                              /cdrom
```

New error: results of `update-initramfs -c -k all`:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-59-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device
    UUID=luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device
    UUID=luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device
    UUID=luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262
```

Comment: hey mate, I know this old but did you ever get it sorted? I seem to be having pretty much the same issue and have been banging my head against a wall for 2 days…

Answer (score 2):

1. Run:

   ```
   dmsetup -u sdc3_crypt <UUID of crypt partition>
   ```
2. Change fstab so `/dev/mapper/>rootpartition` (see below) is named.
3. Remove `luks` prefix in crypttab before UUID (see below).

New working fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#UUID=524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# crypt /dev/sdc3  none luks,initramfs
/dev/mapper/hal9999--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sdc2 during installation
UUID=bbb39977-bf4a-4d8b-b524-7c29a85471d0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdc1 during installation
UUID=94B1-AF12  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/hal9999--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
/dev/mapper/data /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```

New working crypttab:

```
# sdc3_crypt UUID=524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 none luks,discard
#
# luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 UUID=luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 none luk>
# UUID=luks-524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 none luks,discard

sdc3_crypt UUID=524c1ad6-fabe-4f32-9bb0-c8db1286b262 none luks,discard

#sdc3_crypt UUID=JK4UPj-KdoV-yFe5-XBZW-cHFP-JCbV-JsLjPq none luks,discard

data /dev/md0 /root/drive_key luks
```

Now `update-initramfs -c -k` all ran through without any errors, so reboot went through and the filesystem was found.