# Dropping to BusyBox after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, encryption

[image]Some time ago I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption using this guide (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019).
Today after upgrading to 22.04 I get this error:
Volume group "ubuntu -vg" not found
and then drops to BusyBox. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1425001/edit) the question and post a screenshot of the error message (perhaps you can take a photo with your mobile phone)?

Comment: I have added a photo as requested.

Comment: can you try running `cryptsetup` now? What output do you get? see https://askubuntu.com/questions/567730/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-ubuntu-vg-root-doesnt-exist, it is possible that somehow `cryptsetup` got removed during the update and now your disk can't be unencrypted. If that's the case, you will have to boot using a live USB and fix the issue

Comment: I used a live usb and chroot my system and both cryptsetup-initramfs and cryptsetup are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I found out that after the upgrade /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook file was missing the "KEYFILE_PATTERN" line. So I added it, reboot and successfully unlocked the drives.

Comment: I am curious how you added the line, because Ubuntu was not working? If you add that information, it would help other users who face similar issue and come here for help.

Comment: I booted with a live usb and used cryptsetup to unlock my drives. Then I mounted them in /tmp and used chroot to edit the file and update initramfs.